# Newly cloned typescript react-native project riddled with errors

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, typescript, react-native

I just cloned a TypeScript React-Native project at work and it is riddled with a variety of errors on my machine for some reason, the contractor who made the app isn't sure why. Here's a few examples of the errors.

```
import BackButton from "../assets/images/backbutton.png"; - Cannot find module or its corresponding type declarations. ts(2307)

const Title = ({ children }) => - Binding element 'children' implicitly has an 'any' type. ts(7031)
```

Here's my tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "jsx": "react-native",
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "esnext"
    ],
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "noEmit": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "strict": true
  },
  "extends": "expo/tsconfig.base" - File 'expo/tsconfig.base' not found.enter code here
}
```

As you can see it seems like it some sort of configuration problem in regards to typescript.
Any suggestions are appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Image has to be imported using `require` instead of import.

```
const backBtnImg = require('../assets/images/backbutton.png');
```